# About the Phillips curve

Tags: macroeconomics, inflation, unemployment

We know that the Phillips curve takes into account demand shocks, but it's totally susceptible to supply shocks. Are there other types of curves/representations of the unemployment-inflation relationship for these other possible scenarios?